# Deploying Redis on minimal hardware

Tags: redis

I'd like to deploy a Redis server on my Digital Ocean droplet. It's the cheapest droplet which contains 1 CPU and 1GB RAM. Within this droplet is also my website. It has 50 users. Here's the design of what I plan to store:

```
user_id: [1,4,5]
```

`user_id` is the key and the list is a set that contains the posts the user has viewed on a timeline feed. So whenever the user views a post on the feed for more than 3 seconds, that will count as a view and the post id will be stored in the set. Is this a viable solution for the limited hardware I have?

Answer (score 0):

32 bit redis instance can help you in reducing overall memory required to store same mount of data using 64bit, if your data is integer then store them into set and try not to store more data elements per set as **set-max-intset-entries**. 
Coming to processors you may need one more core for redis to perform cleaning dirty data perform background backups and also OS to perform network Operations and other tasks

Comment: Based on my explanation, do you think there's a better way of storing the above set up rather than using Redis?

Comment: SQLite can serve you if given a choice I prefer SQLite for such data lightweight and pretty fast too when data size is small also leave enuf resources to OS. 50 users are not huge, even 1000 post ids per user will be 50k that should be fine with SQLite.

Comment: Hmm, do you think simple requests to save this data in SQLite might overload the server? Since the user will be making requests each time they view a post?

Comment: Not sure on the overhead but you have to test, what I mean is if you are lack in resources SQLite is an alternative for your requirement. 3 seconds per user 1 record that should be fine SQLite can handle that load